# How can access function in MSYS2 packages?

Tags: c, mingw, msys2

For example, [Gtk4-package](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4?repo=mingw64) in msys2. In Gtk4 there is a function something like this :

`gtk_window_set_child(GtkWindow *window, GtkWidget *child)`

This is declerad in `gtkwindow.h` and i want to access to above function. But `gtkwindow.c` file only visible in [gtk4.0-gitlab-repository](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/gtk/gtkwindow.c).

So how can i access `gtkwindow.c` file and functions in package files which exist in msys2?

Comment: Generally you install the appropriate package in msys2 which will usually include headers and a static or shared library. You include the headers and link against the library.

Comment: You can use the pkg-config or pkgconf command to get the required options for compiling and linking a program using gtk4, as described [here](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/compiling.html).